# .htaccess Redirect sub-folder

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Hi I'm not a programmer by any stretch of the imagination and am trying to do a multi 301 redirect in my htaccess file based on the following:

So I have a ton of urls all with similar naming conventions - here is a sample of 2.

```
http://www.hollandsbrook.com/garrett-at-gold/
http://www.hollandsbrook.com/garrett-ace-250/
```

These urls need to redirect to:

```
http://www.hollandsbrook.com/garrett-metal-detectors/garrett-at-gold/
http://www.hollandsbrook.com/garrett-metal-detectors/garrett-ace-250/
```

I could just redirect them 1 line at a time, but I'd like to use regex.

Here's what I was thinking so far but not working:

RewriteRule ^garrett-([a-z])/$ /garrett-metal-detectors/$1/ [R]

Basically i need to redirect any page right off the root that starts with "garrett-" to include the folder path of "garrett-metal-detectors".

Any thoughts would be MUCH appreciated.  Many thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 6):

if you want temprorary redirect use:

```
RewriteRule ^garrett\-([a-z0-9\-]+)/?$ /garrett-metal-detectors/garrett-$1/ [R=302,L]
```

if you want permanent redirect use:

```
RewriteRule ^garrett\-([a-z0-9\-]+)/?$ /garrett-metal-detectors/garrett-$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: dude you rock!  i realized i dont want to redirect the category page (garrett-metal-detectors) so I made a slight edit to your code:

ewriteRule ^garrett\-([a-ln-z\-]+)/?$ /garrett-metal-detectors/garrett-$1/ [R=301,L]

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I'm am not an expert on Regular Expressions, but looks like your reg ex may be a bit off...

try:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^((garrett)(-[a-z0-9]).*)/$ /metal-detectors/$1/ [R]
```

This is looking fro anything starting with "garrett" followed by any letter/number/hyphen combo.

Note: having "garett" in the destination part give you a loop of redirects, so you may have to choose a different word, or remove it all together...